# Semaphore lock is not working properly in Problem

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, posix, semaphore

I have assingment problem which states :

Servers can be designed to limit the number of open
connections. For example, a server may wish to have only N socket connections at any point
in time. As soon as N connections are made, the server will not accept another incoming
connection until an existing connection is released. Write a program using semaphores to
synchronize server activity to limit the number of concurrent connections.

To solve it ,, I have created 2 semaphore :

1. a semaphore that is initialised to N.
2. a sempaphore to provide mutual exclusion.

I have to create in such a way  that if all N connection is made, client must wait till release is made.

I have tried to code it, but code is not working properly :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<pthread.h>
 #include<semaphore.h>
 #include<stdlib.h> 
 #include<string.h>

sem_t allow;
sem_t mutex;

void *acquire(void * arg)
{
 int tid = *(int *)arg;
 tid+=1;
 sem_wait(&mutex);

 sem_wait(&allow);                       


printf("\n Client %d is connected to the server....",tid);
sem_post(&mutex);
sleep(rand()%10);
release(tid);

}
void  release(int num)
{
  printf("\n Client %d releases the Server ....",num);
  sem_post(&allow);                       
}   
void main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
int n;
int i;
printf("\n Enter the number of client :");
scanf("%d", &n);
int maxi=3;         // maximum no. of connection available
sem_init(&allow,0,maxi);  // semaphore that is initialised to maxi. 
                           //no. of connection
sem_init(&mutex,0,1);  // for mutual exclusion

pthread_t thread[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,acquire,&(i));   // Clients are 
                                                  // acquiring ..
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);

sem_destroy(&allow);
sem_destroy(&mutex);
```

}

Its giving different order of execution like , even before acquiring connection (client "x") its releasing the connection like ..

Output :

> Enter the number of client :6
>
> Client 3 is connected to the server....
>
> Client 3 is connected to the server....
>
> Client 4 is connected to the server....
>
> Client 3 releases the Server ....
>
> Client 6 is connected to the server....
>
> Client 3 releases the Server ....
>
> Client 6 is connected to the server....
>
> Client 4 releases the Server ....
>
> Client 1 is connected to the server....
>
> Client 6 releases the Server ....
>
> Client 6 releases the Server ....
>
> Client 1 releases the Server ....

Please help me to correct the code !!

And Sorry for bad title !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is how you create your thread:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,acquire,&(i));
```

As argument for the threads you pass a pointer to the local variable `i`. The problem is that all threads *get the same pointer*, and that can mean multiple threads could dereference it and get the same value!

Normally one should not really cast normal values as pointers, but in a case such as this it's usually accepted. However you should not cast directly to a pointer, but use the [standard fixed width type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) `intptr_t` and then cast that to a pointer:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,acquire,(void *) (intptr_t) i);
```

Then you do the opposite cast in the thread functions:

```
void *acquire(void * arg)
{
    int tid = (int) (intptr_t) arg;
    ...
}
```

That way each thread will have their own "id".